# Ideal way to pass filtered relationship of a model to a template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This is more of what feels like a lot of work / hackish code...

Say I have some models like this:

```
class Semester(models.Model):
     year = models.IntegerField()
     month = models.IntegerField()
     # ... some fields

class Course(models.Model):
     semesters = models.ManyToManyField(Semester)
     # ... some fields

class Section(models.Model):
     semesters = models.ManyToManyField(Semester)
     course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='sections')
     # ... more fields
```

So, for a view, I'm fetching a list of courses by semester. But I also want to list the sections for the courses in a given semester. This creates a dilemma: where do I put this? I can't do it in the templates (because the templates can't really process methods with arguments) and I always have been doing something like this:

```
def view(request, year, month):
    # for simplicity, no error handling
    semester = Semester.objects.get(year=year, month=month)
    courses = []
    for c in Course.objects.filter(semesters=semester):
        courses.append({
            'semesters': c.semesters.all(),
            # repeat for every course field
            'sections': c.sections.filter(semesters=semester),
        })
    # render template with courses variable
```

I feel like this isn't the optimal way, since there is a lot of data translation going on just to the templates happy. I would normally write methods to the model for ones that don't require any arguments, but what about ones that do?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have data translation either way... but if you want to make it a little easier on the template you could return a generator instead of a list of courses and/or semesters.